# Android GridLayout. Margins between GridLayout cells

Tags: android, xml

This is my GridLayout xml code that is inside ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="solutions.elegant.com.procenty.activites.RabatActivity">

 <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="4"
     app:rowCount="3"
     app:columnCount="4"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_splaty"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     app:useDefaultMargins="false"
     app:orientation="horizontal">

     <Button
         style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
         android:id="@+id/btn_0"
         android:text="0" />
     <Button
         style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
         android:id="@+id/btn_1"
         android:text="1"
         />
     <Button
         style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
         android:id="@+id/btn_2"
         android:text="2" />
     <Button
         style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
         android:id="@+id/btn_3"
         android:text="3" />
     <Button
         style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
         android:id="@+id/btn_4"
         android:text="4" />
     <Button
        style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        android:text="5" />
     <Button
        style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        android:text="6" />
     <Button
        style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
        android:id="@+id/btn_7"
        android:text="7" />
     <Button
        style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
        android:id="@+id/btn_8"
        android:text="8" />
     <Button
        style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
        android:id="@+id/btn_9"
        android:text="9" />
     <Button
        style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
        android:id="@+id/btn_kropka"
        android:text="." />
     <Button
        style="@style/MyKeyboardButtons"
        android:id="@+id/btn_remove"
        android:text="l" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is code for button style:

```
<style name="MyKeyboardButtons">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:background">#151515</item>
    <item name="layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">modifyET</item>
</style>
```

And this is the visible result:

[image]

Now i don't like the fact that there is no space between the buttons so first I add to the button style line:

```
 <item name="android:layout_marginRight">2dp</item>
```

The result is:

[image]

I added a margin between gridLayout columns.Now I want to add margin between rows so I again add a line to the button style:

```
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
```

And the result is not what I expected :

[image]

The question is what is wrong here? How can I fix this so I have margins in both
dimensions between the buttons?

Comment: Why not just add padding to the parent?

Comment: Do you mean adding padding to the GridLayout itself? If this is what you mean then it doesn't work. It just add padding between the invisible border of the GridLayout and the GridLayout childrens.

Comment: That's strange. How about `android:useDefaultMargins="false"`, and all margins to be same with  `<item name="android:layout_margin">1dp</item>`  ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for quick comment and sorry for my delay. I tried to use that  solution and unfortunately the result was the same as in my last picture in my original question. And when I tried to add android:useDefaultMargins="false" to gridLayout android studio wanted me to change this line to app:useDefaultMargins="false" so I did that.

Comment: Hi. Maybe the problem is somehow related to the fact that this GridLayout is inside a ConstraintLyout? I edited my question to add a parent of GridLayout because in reality the GridLayout is a part of a bigger layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use only

```
<item name="android:layout_margin">1dp</item>
```