# GridLayout Constraints not working

Tags: java, android, layout, grid-layout

I have made a gridLayout with column and row counts set to 3 each. When I copy and paste the code for X (I am going to make tic tac toe) it overflows and does not change rows whereas in the emulator it shows it in the next row.

[image: Android Studio image showing the problem]

What should I do to make it show in the design page?

The XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:columnCount=" 3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount=" 3">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height=" 100dp"
            android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height=" 100dp"
            android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height=" 100dp"
            android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height=" 100dp"
            android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Make row count to one and take `LinearLayout` inside `GridLayout` use `weight_sum' in `LinearLayout` and put `ImageView` in `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use margins to  keep the GridLayout to center
 [GridLayout margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940287/android-gridlayout-margins-between-gridlayout-cells)       [reference from google android deveelopers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout           
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="368dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount=" 3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount=" 3">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height=" 100dp"
        android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height=" 100dp"
        android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height=" 100dp"
        android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height=" 100dp"
        android:layout_margin=" 8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />
</GridLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can acieve the desired output without using `GridLayout`. You can done using `ContraintLayout` only.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ImageViews must change the value of attribute width and height to 0dp then create vertical and horizontal chains. The ImageViews will equally distribute the spaces left.

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layout_gravity="center"` to each `ImageView`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is making every imageview go to the middle row.... It isn't working

Comment: Its working fine on my device with XML posted by you